# CDO email messaging subject special character error

Tags: asp-classic

I am having trouble with special characters in the subject of emails that are sent through the website.
For instance, Turkish characters show as; `yurtdÄ±ÅŸÄ±na Ã§Ä±kÄ±ÅŸ kapÄ±sÄ± iÃ§in e-posta adresinizi onaylayÄ±n`.
I had the same problem with the body but I managed to solve it by building a function. But I cannot use it with the subject since it isnt an HTML.
What can I do to solve this problem?

```
lngSignupTitle      = "*strWebsiteTitle* için e-posta adresinizi onaylayın"
lngSignupBody       = "<!doctype html><!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class='no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7' lang='en'> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]> <html class='no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8' lang='en'> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]> <html class='no-js lt-ie9' lang='en'> <![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class='no-js' lang='en'> <!--<![endif]--><head><title></title><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'><style type='text/css'>/* Mobile-specific Styles */@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { table[class=w0], td[class=w0] { width: 0 !important; }table[class=w10], td[class=w10], img[class=w10] { width:10px !important; }table[class=w15], td[class=w15], img[class=w15] { width:5px !important; }table[class=w30], td[class=w30], img[class=w30] { width:10px !important; }table[class=w60], td[class=w60], img[class=w60] { width:10px !important; }table[class=w125], td[class=w125], img[class=w125] { width:80px !important; }table[class=w130], td[class=w130], img[class=w130] { width:55px !important; }table[class=w140], td[class=w140], img[class=w140] { width:90px !important; }table[class=w160], td[class=w160], img[class=w160] { width:180px !important; }table[class=w170], td[class=w170], img[class=w170] { width:100px !important; }table[class=w180], td[class=w180], img[class=w180] { width:80px !important; }table[class=w195], td[class=w195], img[class=w195] { width:80px !important; }table[class=w220], td[class=w220], img[class=w220] { width:80px !important; }table[class=w240], td[class=w240], img[class=w240] { width:180px !important; }table[class=w255], td[class=w255], img[class=w255] { width:185px !important; }table[class=w275], td[class=w275], img[class=w275] { width:135px !important; }table[class=w280], td[class=w280], img[class=w280] { width:135px !important; }table[class=w300], td[class=w300], img[class=w300] { width:140px !important; }table[class=w325], td[class=w325], img[class=w325] { width:95px !important; }table[class=w360], td[class=w360], img[class=w360] { width:140px !important; }table[class=w410], td[class=w410], img[class=w410] { width:180px !important; }table[class=w470], td[class=w470], img[class=w470] { width:200px !important; }table[class=w580], td[class=w580], img[class=w580] { width:280px !important; }table[class=w640], td[class=w640], img[class=w640] { width:300px !important; }table[class*=hide], td[class*=hide], img[class*=hide], p[class*=hide], span[class*=hide] { display:none !important; }table[class=h0], td[class=h0] { height: 0 !important; }p[class=footer-content-left] { text-align: center !important; }#headline p { font-size: 30px !important; }.article-content, #left-sidebar{ -webkit-text-size-adjust: 90% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 90% !important; }.header-content, .footer-content-left {-webkit-text-size-adjust: 80% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 80% !important;}img { height: auto; line-height: 100%;} } /* Client-specific Styles */#outlook a { padding: 0; }/* Force Outlook to provide a 'view in browser' button. */body { width: 100% !important; }.ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }.ExternalClass { width: 100%; display:block !important; } /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width *//* Reset Styles *//* Add 100px so mobile switch bar doesn't cover street address. */body { background-color: #FFED90; margin: 0; padding: 0; }img { outline: none; text-decoration: none; display: block;}br, strong br, b br, em br, i br { line-height:100%; }h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { line-height: 100% !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { color: blue !important; }h1 a:active, h2 a:active, h3 a:active, h4 a:active, h5 a:active, h6 a:active {color: red !important; }/* Preferably not the same color as the normal header link color. There is limited support for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added just for good measure. */h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited, h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited { color: purple !important; }/* Preferably not the same color as the normal header link color. There is limited support for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added just for good measure. */ table td, table tr { border-collapse: collapse; }.yshortcuts, .yshortcuts a, .yshortcuts a:link,.yshortcuts a:visited, .yshortcuts a:hover, .yshortcuts a span {color: black; text-decoration: none !important; border-bottom: none !important; background: none !important;}/* Body text color for the New Yahoo. This example sets the font of Yahoo's Shortcuts to black. *//* This most probably won't work in all email clients. Don't include <code _tmplitem='664' > blocks in email. */code { white-space: normal; word-break: break-all;}#background-table { background-color: #FFED90; }/* Webkit Elements */#top-bar { border-radius:6px 6px 0px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px; -webkit-border-radius:6px 6px 0px 0px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }#top-bar a { font-weight: bold; color: #A8D46F; text-decoration: none;}#footer { border-radius:0px 0px 6px 6px; -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px; -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 6px 6px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }/* Fonts and Content */body, td { font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif; }.header-content, .footer-content-left, .footer-content-right { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; }/* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes on header and footer. */.header-content { font-size: 12px; color: #FFFFFF; }.header-content a { font-weight: bold; color: #A8D46F; text-decoration: none; }#headline p { color: #444444; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 36px; text-align: center; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:30px; }#headline p a { color: #444444; text-decoration: none; }.article-title { font-size: 18px; line-height:24px; color: #341139; font-weight:bold; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:18px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif; }.article-title a { color: #341139; text-decoration: none; }.article-title.with-meta {margin-bottom: 0;}.article-meta { font-size: 13px; line-height: 20px; color: #ccc; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0;}.article-content { font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #3C3251; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 18px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif; }.article-content a { color: #359668; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; }.article-content img { max-width: 100% }.article-content ol, .article-content ul { margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:18px; margin-left:19px; padding:0; }.article-content li { font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #3C3251; }.article-content li a { color: #359668; text-decoration:underline; }.article-content p {margin-bottom: 15px;}.footer-content-left { font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; color: #FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; }.footer-content-left a { color: #A8D46F; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }.footer-content-right { font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; color: #FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; }.footer-content-right a { color: #A8D46F; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }#footer { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }#footer a { color: #A8D46F; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; }#permission-reminder { white-space: normal; }#street-address { color: #FFFFFF; white-space: normal; }</style><!--[if gte mso 9]><style _tmplitem='664' >.article-content ol, .article-content ul { margin: 0 0 0 24px; padding: 0; list-style-position: inside;}</style><![endif]--></head><body><table id='background-table' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tbody><tr><td align='center' bgcolor='#FFED90'> <table class='w640' style='margin:0 10px;' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='640'> <tbody> <tr> <td class='w640' height='20' width='640'></td> </tr> <tr> <td id='header' class='w640' align='center' bgcolor='#359668' width='640'> <div style='text-align: left' align='left'> <a href='http://www.kampuster.com'> <img id='customHeaderImage' label='Header Image' editable='true' src='http://www.kampuster.com/images/inner_logo.png' class='w640' style='display: inline' align='top' border='0' width='147'> </a> </div> </td> </tr> <tr> <td class='w640' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' height='30' width='640'></td> </tr> <tr id='simple-content-row'><td class='w640' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' width='640'> <table class='w640' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='640'> <tbody><tr> <td class='w30' width='30'></td> <td class='w580' width='580'> <repeater> <layout label='Text only'> <table class='w580' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='580'> <tbody><tr> <td class='w580' width='580'> <p class='article-title' align='left'> <singleline label='Title'>lütfen *strWebsiteTitle* için e-posta adresinizi onaylayın</singleline></p> <div class='article-content' align='left'> <multiline label='Description'> <p> Merhaba *strFirstName*, </p> <br /> <p>*strWebsiteTitle* üyeliğinizin aktif hale gelmesi için lütfen aşağıdaki bağlantıya tıklayın:</p> <p><a href='*strWebsiteURL*/inner.asp?Section=myaccount&SubSection=confirm&EmailAddress=*strEmailAddress*&Active_Code=*strActive_Code*'>*strWebsiteURL*/inner.asp?Section=myaccount&SubSection=confirm&amp;s=1&amp;EmailAddress=*strEmailAddress*&Active_Code=*strActive_Code*</p> <p>Teşekkürler,<br />*strWebsiteTitle*</p> </multiline> </div> </td> </tr> <tr><td class='w580' height='10' width='580'></td></tr> </tbody></table> </layout> </repeater> </td> <td class='w30' width='30'></td> </tr> </tbody></table></td></tr> <tr><td class='w640' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' height='15' width='640'></td></tr> <tr> <td class='w640' width='640'> <table id='footer' class='w640' bgcolor='#000000' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='640'> <tbody><tr><td class='w30' width='30'></td><td class='w580 h0' height='30' width='360'></td><td class='w0' width='60'></td><td class='w0' width='160'></td><td class='w30' width='30'></td></tr> <tr> <td class='w30' width='30'></td> <td class='w580' valign='top' width='360'> <span class='hide'> <p id='permission-reminder' class='footer-content-left' align='left'> <span>*strWebsiteURL* üzerinden bu e-posta adresi ile kayıt işleminde bulunulduğu için bu mesajı aldınız</span><br> <span>Eğer bu işlemi siz yapmadiysanız, lütfen bizimle iletişime geçin</span> <span>*strWebsiteEURL*</span> </p></span> </td> <td class='hide w0' width='60'></td> <td class='hide w0' valign='top' width='160'> <p id='street-address' class='footer-content-right' align='right'><span></span></p> </td> <td class='w30' width='30'></td> </tr> <tr><td class='w30' width='30'></td><td class='w580 h0' height='15' width='360'></td><td class='w0' width='60'></td><td class='w0' width='160'></td><td class='w30' width='30'></td></tr></tbody> </table></td> </tr> <tr> <td class='w640' height='60' width='640'></td> </tr> </tbody></table> </td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>"


        MailSubject = strMessageTitle
        MailBody = strMessageBody

        Set objEmail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        objEmail.To     = MailTo
        objEmail.From       = MailFrom
        objEmail.Subject    = MailSubject
        objEmail.HTMLBody   = MailBody
        objEmail.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8" 
        objEmail.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"

Function trchar(rtt)
    ii  = Replace(rtt,"ı","&#305;")
    rtt = ii 
    OO  = Replace(rtt,"Ö","&#214;")
    rtt = OO 
    Oo  = Replace(rtt,"ö","&#246;")
    rtt = Oo 
    UU  = Replace(rtt,"Ü","&#220;")
    rtt = UU 
    Uu  = Replace(rtt,"ü","&#252;")
    rtt = Uu 
    CC  = Replace(rtt,"Ç","&#199;")
    rtt = CC 
    Cc  = Replace(rtt,"ç","&#231;")
    rtt = Cc 
    GG  = Replace(rtt,"Ğ","&#286;")
    rtt = GG 
    Gg  = Replace(rtt,"ğ","&#287;")
    rtt = Gg 
    SS  = Replace(rtt,"Ş","&#350;")
    rtt = SS 
    Ss  = Replace(rtt,"ş","&#351;")
    trchar = Ss 
End Function
```

Comment: is the string in the variable MailBody utf-8 encoded? is your asp file saved as utf-8? have you set Codepage and charset to utf-8 in your asp?

Comment: can you post the turkish string which you want to have as subject so i can test this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works for me:

```
<%
Response.Codepage = 65001 
Response.Charset = "utf-8" 

MailTo = ""
MailFrom = ""
MailSubject = "Evinizdeymişim"
MailBody = "<b>Evinizdeymişim</b>"

Set objEmail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objConf = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 

With objConf.Fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = ""
    .item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = ""
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")  = ""

    .Update 
End With

Set objEmail.Configuration = objConf

objEmail.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8" 

objEmail.To         = MailTo
objEmail.From       = MailFrom
objEmail.Subject    = MailSubject
objEmail.HTMLBody   = MailBody
objEmail.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "utf-8"

objEmail.send

set objEmail = nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried .BodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8" and other combination of similar settings but what really fixed the issue for me was adding this near the top: 
Response.Codepage = 65001
Response.Charset = "utf-8"
When you think about it, this tells the application server how to deliver the content of CDO.message to the mail server.  I removed  .BodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8" and it kept working.